# Read a file from a specic line and N lines at a time

Tags: python

I am going to read a file starting from a specific line and read N number of lines at a time. So far I read N number of line at a time like this:

```
from itertools import islice

n = 10                                                                                    
with open(fname, 'r') as f:                                                               
    while True:                                                                           
        next_n_lines = list(islice(f, n))                                                 
        for line in next_n_lines:                                                         
            print line.rstrip()                                                           
        if not next_n_lines:                                                              
            break
```

Any help on start reading it from a specific line number.

Comment: You could use a counter variable to skip doing anything until it reaches a certain value, then reset it, or perhaps use modulo: `x % y == 0` if you want to do something only with every n line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple solution using `itertools.islice`:

```
N = 100  # starting line number
n = 10   # size of a chunk
with open(fname) as f:
    f = islice(f, N, None)  # creates an iterator that starts after N lines
    while True:
        next_n_lines = list(islice(f, n))
        for line in next_n_lines:
            print line.rstrip()
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `islice(f, None, N)`?

Comment: Well, we could also do something like `list(islice(f, N))` to consume the `N` first lines. But what I did is reassign to the file an iterator that starts at the Nth line.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use fileinput as shown below?

```
startNo = 1
N = 10
for line in fileinput.input("fileName"):
  if fileinput.lineno() > startNo + N:
    break
  if fileinput.lineno() >= startNo:
    print fileinput.lineno(),line
```